# Calculating grouped sequences in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr, sequence

I am working with a data set similar to the sample I created below, where each customer's activity is logged:

```
sample_data <- data.frame(customer_id = c(1000, 1000,1000, 1000,1000, 1000, 2000, 3000,3000,3000, 4000,4000),
           activity_date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-29", "2020-03-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-01", "2020-03-04", "2020-05-22", "2020-03-05", "2020-06-01"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
           activity = c("like", "purchase", "like", "visit", "email", "like", "purchase", "visit", "purchase", "visit", "like", "email"))
```

For my final data set, I would like to add two columns with calculated "sequences" to the data, where each column indicates a different kind of sequence.

1. **General sequence**: Grouped on a `customer_id` level, each rule should be counted consecutively. However, rules happening on the **same date** should also indicate the **same sequence**, meaning that counting only continues when the date changes.
2. **Rule sequence**: Grouped on a `customer_id` level, each individual rule should start with the sequence 1 and continue counting on a rule-basis, depending on how often the specific rule appears per customer. Again, rules happening on the same date should indicate the same sequence.

I have come up with the following `dplyr` code so far, which has two issues:

```
test_result <- sample_data  %>%
  dplyr::group_by(customer_id) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(activity_date) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(general_sequence=1:n()) %>% dplyr::ungroup()
```

- Rules tracked on the same date do not have the same sequence. As you can see in the `test_result`, the count starts with 1 and continues counting, even when rules were tracked on the same day.
- I did not manage to calculate the column "Rule sequence" at all. I assume that I would need to apply a  different grouping in order to get the result (maybe based on "rule"?)

For more clarity, I created a table that shows how I would like the final result to look like:

```
final_data <- data.frame(customer_id = c(1000, 1000,1000, 1000,1000, 1000, 2000, 3000,3000,3000, 4000,4000),
                         activity_date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-29", "2020-03-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-01", "2020-03-04", "2020-05-22", "2020-03-05", "2020-06-01"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                         activity = c("like", "purchase", "like", "visit", "purchase", "like", "purchase", "visit", "purchase", "visit", "like", "email"),
                         general_sequence = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
                         rule_sequence = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1))
```

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: your `sample_data` and `final_data` don't have same `activity` column also  `rule_sequance`  changes values for same acitvity on same date and that is something you said you don't want?

Comment: Can you explain your rule sequence? I didn't get that. What is rule in `continue counting on a rule-basis, depending on how often the specific rule appears per customer` ?

Answer (score 1):

This would be one approach using {dplyr} and `data.table::rleid`:

```r
library(dplyr)

sample_data %>% 
  group_by(customer_id) %>%
  mutate(general_sequence = data.table::rleid(activity_date)) %>% 
  group_by(customer_id, activity) %>%
  mutate(rule_sequence = row_number())

#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#> # Groups:   customer_id, activity [9]
#>    customer_id activity_date activity general_sequence rule_sequence
#>          <dbl> <date>        <chr>               <int>         <int>
#>  1        1000 2020-01-01    like                    1             1
#>  2        1000 2020-01-01    purchase                1             1
#>  3        1000 2020-01-01    like                    1             2
#>  4        1000 2020-01-01    visit                   1             1
#>  5        1000 2020-02-29    email                   2             1
#>  6        1000 2020-03-01    like                    3             3
#>  7        2000 2020-01-02    purchase                1             1
#>  8        3000 2020-01-01    visit                   1             1
#>  9        3000 2020-03-04    purchase                2             1
#> 10        3000 2020-05-22    visit                   3             2
#> 11        4000 2020-03-05    like                    1             1
#> 12        4000 2020-06-01    email                   2             1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>